# "The only thought on one's mind" vs. "in one's mind"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, possessives, in-on

I heard the following lines in a song:

> that I could be the only thought **in her mind**
>   as she was **in mine**.

I was wondering if it shouldn't be *on* instead, in both cases. Is the *in* variant grammatical and idiomatic? Is this poetic license or perhaps some local dialect?

Comment: So, "I" is a thought? Funny. The only ***thought on my mind*** was ***why lunch had not been served***. A thought is not usually a single person pronoun. /...that I could be the only person on her mind, as she was on mine/.

Comment: It was written in a song and I was wondering whether it was correct or not as it sounds weird to me. thank you.

Comment: If it's in a song, what does the song SAY: in or on? Why are you asking the question rather than quoting the song?

Comment: because the song says "in her mind as she was in mine" so I thought the right structure was" on(one's)mind "

Comment: In the future please include all that information right from the get-go. It can be frustrating for people to have to work to extract it from you bit by bit. Thank you.

Comment: I will certainly do it ,thank you both for your answers .

Comment: Songwriters take all sorts of liberties, so, it's fine. For the songwriter, the person was in his/her mind.

Answer (score 0):

Songs follow poetic licence as much as any rule and "On" and "in" my mind are almost interchangeable, but "On" sometimes implies a worry or a persistent thought, where "in" merely describes a thought, which might well be fleeting…

Answer (score -1):

*to be on one's mind* = thinking about someone/something
*to be in one's mind* = to be in her/his thoughts